# Discord bot in python, check if command is empty

Tags: python, discord

I have a simple question, I want to add to a bot a command where if a  user replies to a message using the command, the bot gets that message and the author of the message the user replied to and save it to a database, this was done easily. Now I want also to add to this function a condition where if the user uses the same command without replying but instead writing a message and tagging another user, it stores the message and the tagged user in a variable to be used for the database.  If the user uses the command without any message and only tagging a user it tells the user that they need to add a message, or the other way around that they need to tag a user.

```
@bot.command()
async def commandme(ctx,*member=None,message=None):
   if message: 
        if member: 
             #here I execute the command using message and member
   else
     await ctx.send("Please either reply using the command or write a message while tagging a user using teh command")
```

This is the idea that I have so far but it seems to not work since when testing to see what happens , message always  returns none and member returns just the object even though I use the same method to tag a user for other commands. Is there something I am missing in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. But I will try to answer it as I read it.

I do not think the module will play well with the way you are defining the arguments. It should be `commandme(ctx, member=None, *message)`. As you want the `message` to be collected in a tuple.

The caller of the `commandme` would have to pass the arguments like this `ctx, Member, message=Message`. That is with the "message" argument passed as a keyword and only 1 object, while the `member` argument will collect everything in a tuple.